# How to use By.parameter in Selenium Java code?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium, I am stuck in a specific situation code wise. I am trying to write a generic code for checkboxes, like below.

```
public void CheckBox(By by, String element)
{
    driver.findElement(By.by(""));
}
```

The above generic code, which later can be used in Tests. Where user will use this function will pass the element and by what he needs to search. (by Xpath, id or name etc.)

I can write if_else or Switch but, that will too much of a code, is there any way where can use a direct parameter with **By object** or is there any other way to do this. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`findElement` receives `By` as parameter

```
public void CheckBox(By by)
{
    driver.findElement(by);
}
```

And call it like this

```
CheckBox(By.id("id")); // or any other locator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CheckBox(By by, String element) {
            driver.findElement(by).sendKeys(element);
}
```

now you can call this CheckBox method into @Test code

```
  @Test
  public void fillLoginDetails() {
        CheckBox(By.id("ap_customer_name"),"bonn");
        CheckBox(By.id("ap_email"),"absvdgdhdh@gmail.com");
        CheckBox(By.name("password"),"bo123456");
        CheckBox(By.id("ap_password_check"),"bon123456");
  }
```

Comment: Hi Ramana, Your answer is good and it worked, but I was wondering if its possible to, I mean in the test, I just want to pass, type and element identifier(value),

like This
: PageObject po = new PageObject(driver);
  po.CheckBox(id, element);
Can I do this, I want to make is simple and less complicated for whoever write the test automation.

Comment: @ajinkyaJahagirdar yes it is possible.public void CheckBox(String cam, String value) {
   driver.findElement(By.id(cam)).sendKeys(value);
  }     and Test code is  CheckBox("ap_email","ra@gmail.com");

Comment: ajinkya Check @Guy 's answer for your requirement.